# dart proxy for easyrtc: type 'JsObject' is not a subtype of type 'JsFunction'

Tags: dart, easyrtc

I'm experimenting some with [easyrtc](http://easyrtc.com) using dart. Following [this](http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js.html) the file would be something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

var selfEasyrtcid = "";
var easyrtc;

void main() {
  easyrtc = new js.Proxy(js.context.easyrtc);
}

void something(){
  easyrtc.someFunction();
}
```

but when I try to run that in dartium it crashes with:

> Exception: type 'JsObject' is not a subtype of type 'JsFunction' of
>   'constructor'. (package:js/js.dart:168) Breaking on exception: type
>   'JsObject' is not a subtype of type 'JsFunction' of 'constructor'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show how this should be called in pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc you don't need to call `new JsObject` that should be used to do `new xxx` on JS side. Simply do :

```
easyrtc = js.context.easyrtc;
```